# ReadOnly Form Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Form with two fields, Key and Value.

This is displayed in a form with:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=> m.Key)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Key)

@Html.LabelFor(m=> m.Value)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Value)
```

Note that the user cannot edit m.Key, only m.Value.

This works.  However, what posts with the Form is only m.Value which I would expect.  However, I really do need m.Key to be returned as well.

How can I do this?

Greg

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.Key)
```

This will create a hidden input with your key that will get POSTed back when your form is submitted.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.